# Combine two images

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image

I would like to take an image and duplicate it. Then increase it by 105% and overlay it on the original image.

What is the correct way to do this on iOS?

Comment: For what purpose? To save it as a new image or just to display it on screen? How would you blend it? Just set alpha to 50% or something more advanced?

Comment: I would like to save it as an image. Yes, alpha to 50%.

Comment: What do you mean by increase it? Scale the size? Or something else?

Comment: I would like to take an image, duplicate it. Scale the duplicate by 105% and then overlay the scaled duplicate onto the original. Outputting a single image.

Answer (score 0):

This is your basic code for drawing the image and then saving it as an image again:

```
- (UIImage *)renderImage:(UIImage *)image atSize:(CGSize)size
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)];

        // draw anything else into the context

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
```

Where it says "draw anything else into the context" you can draw the image at a reduced size by setting the appropriate rect to draw in. Then, call the `renderImage` method with whatever size you want the full image to be. You can use `CGContextSetAlpha` to set the transparency.

Comment: Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and specify the scale based on the original image's scale.